# Is it possible to have two different font sizes in one spinner

Tags: java, android, font-size, android-spinner

I want to know if it is possible, when you have 1 Spinner, to get 2 different font sizes in it. I want to show an abbreviation on a spinner and then the full word after it, but smaller.
See picture for exmaple (that is done with Photoshop):

[image]

Comment: Yes. You can do it by customize it.

Comment: @SpK That word did it (Customize) found some tuts on internet now. (Really stupid I couldn't think if that word, english is not my mother tongue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to customize the Spinner View via your own Adapter and Custom Layout. Check out this tutorial : http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/